# python settimeout permanent print

Tags: python, sockets, timeout

I have the next undesirable behaviour:

```
def run(self):
        self._socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self._socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", self.port()))
        self._socket.listen(5)
        self._socket.settimeout(5.0)
        while not self.finish.isSet():
            try:
                conn, addr = self._socket.accept()
                c = connection(conn, addr)
                self.activeconn.append(c)
                c.start()
                print "New session from address {}".format(addr)
            except Exception as e:
                print e
            self.activeconn = self.child_list()
        self._socket.close()
        print "Server is closing..."
        for conn in self.activeconn:
            conn.join()
        time.sleep(4)
        print "Server is closed"
```

Here I have echo server with timeout set by settimeout(5.0). The problem is my console prints "timed out" every time timeout is expired. Can I turn this off somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a timeout occurs during an operation on a socket, the `socket.timeout` exception is raised. In your code, you are catching that exception and printing it:

```
try:
    conn, addr = self._socket.accept()
    # ...
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

If you want to prevent "timed out" lines from appearing in your output, just catch the exception and suppress it:

```
try:
    conn, addr = self._socket.accept()
    # ...
except socket.error:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print e
```